# ArrayAdapter showing the output on the screen only after i lock and unlock my phone

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, android-arrayadapter

i am trying to fetch some data (name,category and fan_count) of all the pages owned by the user on facebook and then displaying the result in a ListView using ArrayAdapter.

i made my custom array adapter

```
public class PageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Page> {
public PageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Page> pages) {
    super(context, 0, pages);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View listItemView = convertView;
    if (listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.list_item_layout, parent, false);
    }
    final Page currentPage = getItem(position);
    TextView nameText = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView categoryText = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.category);
    TextView fanCountText = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.fan_count);

    nameText.setText(currentPage.getmName());
    categoryText.setText(currentPage.getmCategory());
    fanCountText.setText(currentPage.getmFanCount());

    return listItemView;

}
```

here is my page class

```
public class Page {
private String mName;
private String mCategory;
private String mFanCount;

public Page(String name, String category, String fanCount){
    mName = name;
    mCategory = category;
    mFanCount = fanCount;
}

public String getmName(){return mName;}
public String getmCategory(){return mCategory;}
public String getmFanCount(){return mFanCount;}}
```

i already logged into facebook and called an intent which opens PageActivity class where the ArrayAdapter should fetch data and should show the result through a ListView.

```
public class PageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private String category, fan_count, name;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_page);

    final ArrayList<Page> pages = new ArrayList<>();

    Bundle param = new Bundle();
    param.putString("fields", "category,fan_count,name");
    new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "/me/accounts",
            param,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject root = new JSONObject(response.getRawResponse());
                        JSONArray data = root.getJSONArray("data");

                        for(int i=0 ; i<data.length() ; i++){
                            JSONObject dataRoot = data.getJSONObject(i);
                            name = dataRoot.getString("name");
                            category = dataRoot.getString("category");
                            fan_count = dataRoot.getString("fan_count");

                            pages.add(new Page(name, category, fan_count));
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
    ).executeAsync();

    ListView pageListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    final PageAdapter adapter = new PageAdapter(this, pages);
    pageListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}}
```

now the ArrayAdapter is fetching the data successfully but shows the result in the listview **only if i lock and unlock my phone once**, i have no clue what is wrong with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should call notifyDataSetChange method of adapter after adding all rows.
so your code should change like this:

```
new GraphRequest(
        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
        "/me/accounts",
        param,
        HttpMethod.GET,
        new GraphRequest.Callback() {
            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject root = new JSONObject(response.getRawResponse());
                    JSONArray data = root.getJSONArray("data");

                    for(int i=0 ; i<data.length() ; i++){
                        JSONObject dataRoot = data.getJSONObject(i);
                        name = dataRoot.getString("name");
                        category = dataRoot.getString("category");
                        fan_count = dataRoot.getString("fan_count");

                        pages.add(new Page(name, category, fan_count));

                    }
                    //**********this line added!!!!!*************
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
).executeAsync();
```

Comment: this worked..thank you so much.......but will you please explain what you did here.

Comment: this line added after the adding loop of rows : 
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); after any change in adapter you should call notifyDataSetChange , this method refresh  the view of list

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because you're calling the `pages.add...` on a background thread.

I don't remember if Facebook does this or not.

As a simple test, change your code to this:

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        pages.add(new Page(name, category, fan_count));
    }
});
```

If it works, then you know its a thread issue, and you'll have to take it from there

Answer (score 0):

You're displaying the data in the Adapter before the Request has a chance to finish.

I'm assuming the pages object (not sure where it's defined) is being saved even through lifecycle methods so the creation of the new Adapter takes the new data into account. You can try to recreate the adapter after the request finishes.